# Biopython local BLAST database error

Tags: python, database, path, biopython, blast

I am trying to run blastx locally with the "nr" database using Biopython's NcbiblastxCommandline tool but I always get the following error regarding the protein database search path:

```
>>> from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastxCommandline
>>> nr = "/Users/Priya/Documents/Python/ncbi-blast-2.2.26+/bin/nr.pal"
>>> infile = "/Users/Priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/opuntia.txt"
>>> blastx = "/Users/Priya/Documents/Python/ncbi-blast-2.2.26+/bin/blastx"
>>> outfile = "/Users/Priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/opuntia_python_local.xml"
>>> blastx_cline = NcbiblastxCommandline(blastx, query = infile, db = nr, evalue = 0.001, out = outfile)
>>> stdout, stderr = blastx_cline()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File     "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py", line 443, in __call__
stdout_str, stderr_str)
Bio.Application.ApplicationError: Command '/Users/Priya/Documents/Python/ncbi-blast-2.2.26+/bin/blastx -out /Users/Priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/opuntia_python_local.xml -query /Users/Priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/opuntia.txt -db /Users/Priya/Documents/Python/ncbi-blast-2.2.26+/bin/nr.pal -evalue 0.001' returned non-zero exit status 2, 'BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for protein database [/Users/Priya/Documents/Python/ncbi-blast-2.2.26+/bin/nr.pal] in search path [/Users/Priya::]'
```

I am not sure how to change the path to point to the nr database that I downloaded, but I thought I pointed to it correctly since I can run this code from the command line without any problems:

```
Priyas-iMac:~ Priya$ /Users/priya/Documents/Python/ncbi-blast-2.2.26+/bin/blastx -query /Users/priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/opuntia.txt -db /Users/priya/Documents/Python/ncbi-blast-2.2.26+/bin/nr -out /Users/priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/opuntia_local.xml -evalue 0.001 -outfmt 5
```

The above command line code creates an xml file of the blast results as I would expect.

Any help solving this problem with the Biopython NCBI command line tools would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `nr` variable ends in `nr.pal`. `nr` (without `.pal`) should be fine. If removing `pal` doesn't work. You can try setting up an `.ncbirc` file in your home directory which has this:

```
[BLAST]
BLASTDB=/directory/path/to/blast/databases
```

It basically sets up an environment variable for blast database lookups. Afterwards, you can simply use `nr` (no path required) in your `nr` variable.

By the way, you can check the command line constructed by `NcbiblastxCommandline` using `print blastx_cline`. My guess is it's not the same as the one you typed manually.

EDIT: Check out http://www.biostars.org/ for bioinformatics-specific questions similar to StackExchange's format.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks for catching my typo! And thanks for the biostar advice!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the command that works lists a different db than the one being called from within the code sample:

```
# In the code
-db /Users/Priya/Documents/Python/ncbi-blast-2.2.26+/bin/nr.pal
```

vs.

```
# From the command line
-db /Users/priya/Documents/Python/ncbi-blast-2.2.26+/bin/nr
```

Try changing the assignment of that path to nr in line 2 so that it reflects the path without '.pal' that you use from the command line.